# Is it possible to write this generally? XPATH 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, schematron

Is it possible to write this test more generally. I´ve sat on it for hours and I can´t figure out :D.

```
 <pattern>
            <title>Pravidla pro měnu(CZK/USD)</title>
            <rule context="/o:objednávka/o:položky">
                <report test="(contains(o:položka[1]/o:cena/@měna,'CZK') and 
                    contains(o:položka[2]/o:cena/@měna,'USD'))or(contains(o:položka[2]/o:cena/@měna,'CZK') and 
                    contains(o:položka[1]/o:cena/@měna,'USD'))">V objednávce 
                    musí být jen jedna měna.</report>     
            </rule>
```

**XML document**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="cssTrans.css" type="text/css" ?>
<?xml-model href="objednavka.sch" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<objednávka xmlns="urn:x-eshop:document-schemas:purchase-order">
    <položky>
        <položka kód="a">
            <název>Sekačka na trávu</název>
            <počet mj="ks">1</počet>
            <cena měna="USD">0.9</cena>
            <popis>http://example.org/sekacka.html</popis>
        </položka>
        <položka kód="d">
            <název>Travní semeno</název>
            <počet mj="kg">2.5</počet>
            <cena měna="CZK">18001</cena>
        </položka>
    </položky>
</objednávka>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your rule and your instance document, I strongly suspect that you don't want a "contains" test but rather an "=" test. People often imagine that the English phrase "attribute contains value" should translate to XPath `contains(@att, 'val')`, but that's wrong; it should be `@att = 'val'`.

I think the constraint you are trying to express is that there are two položka elements and in one of them, the cena/@měna attribute has the value USD, and in the other, it has the value CZK. I would express that as

```
o:položka/o:cena/@měna ='CZK' and o:položka/o:cena/@měna = 'USD'
```

remembering that in XPath, "=" is existential: `a/b/c='USD'` means that at least one node selected by `a/b/c` has the value `'USD'`.

Comment: I am reading your book it's awsome :) I am gonna use it to write my bachelor's thesis.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
contains('USD|CZK|USD', string-join(o:položka/o:cena/@měna, '|'))
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:o="urn:x-eshop:document-schemas:purchase-order">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/o:objednávka/o:položky">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "contains('USD|CZK|USD', string-join(o:položka/o:cena/@měna, '|'))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<objednávka xmlns="urn:x-eshop:document-schemas:purchase-order">
    <položky>
        <položka kód="a">
            <název>Sekačka na trávu</název>
            <počet mj="ks">1</počet>
            <cena měna="USD">0.9</cena>
            <popis>http://example.org/sekacka.html</popis>
        </položka>
        <položka kód="d">
            <název>Travní semeno</název>
            <počet mj="kg">2.5</počet>
            <cena měna="CZK">18001</cena>
        </položka>
    </položky>
</objednávka>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
true
```

**If the same expression is evaluated on this XML document:**

```
<objednávka xmlns="urn:x-eshop:document-schemas:purchase-order">
    <položky>
        <položka kód="a">
            <název>Sekačka na trávu</název>
            <počet mj="ks">1</počet>
            <cena měna="USD">0.9</cena>
            <popis>http://example.org/sekacka.html</popis>
        </položka>
        <položka kód="d">
            <název>Travní semeno</název>
            <počet mj="kg">2.5</počet>
            <cena měna="USD">18001</cena>
        </položka>
    </položky>
</objednávka>
```

**then again the correct result is produced:**

```
false
```